# Return every nth record in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have time series data and I want to query Elasticsearch by using time ranges with a fixed set of 2000 records.

I have this query

```
GET http://IP:9200/MYINDEX/_search
{ 
   "_source": ["XXX1", "XXX2","timestamp"],
    "sort" : 
        { "@timestamp" : {"order" : "asc"}},
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
                "gte" : "2017-02-10T10:55:31,259Z",
                "lte" : "2017-02-10T10:55:32,272Z"
            }   
        }
}
```

Is it possible to return only every 5th or 10th record?
I found some filter scripts but none of them seems to work.

Since there could be millions of records in one index its crucial to limit the number of returned values!

EDIT: rework query becasue filtered was replaced by bool:

```html
  {
   "_source":[
      "XXX1",
      "XXX2",
      "timestamp"
   ],
   "sort":{
      "@timestamp":{
         "order":"asc"
      }
   },
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "range":{
               "@timestamp":{
                  "gte":"2017-02-10T10:55:31,259Z",
                  "lte":"2017-02-10T10:55:32,272Z"
               }
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "script":{
               "script":"doc['@timestamp'].value % 5 == 0"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one way to do it. You can add a field which can behave like an auto increment field of a DB.

Then you can add a filter to the query that you want to run.

```
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['auto_increment'].value % n == 0",
          "params" : {
            "n" : 5
          }
        }
      }
```

This should work for indexes that have time series data and are going to be searched for a range. It will not work properly if you have an added text search to the field.

For the query that you are trying it would transform into something like this.

```
GET http://IP:9200/MYINDEX/_search
{ 
   "_source": ["XXX1", "XXX2","timestamp"],
    "sort" : 
        { "@timestamp" : {"order" : "asc"}},
    "query" : {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "range" : {
                    "@timestamp" : {
                        "gte" : "2017-02-10T10:55:31,259Z",
                        "lte" : "2017-02-10T10:55:32,272Z"
               }   
           }  
           },
           "filter": {
               "script": {
                    "script": "doc['auto_increment'].value % 5 == 0"

        }
           }
        } 

}
}
```

For reference do look into [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)

Comment: thanks a lot. i tried this approach but had no luck with the syntax. where exactly do i have to place it within my query?

Comment: I have added the syntax. Have not been able to test it though. Give a try. You might have to do minor tweaks. Let me know if it works.

Comment: hey, thank you very much ... i found that i had do rework something because filtered was replaced by "bool".

Comment: i removed the "param" section because there was an error [script] query does not support [params] which i can not really figure out why!

Comment: with the above fix in the orig. post it worked! thanks again for your solution!